# C# creating a database programmatically with SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a database, but once created, I cannot connect to it.

The server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and using .Net 4.5. We're creating the database with SMO, but we're usually using [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) to connect and query the database.

This is the code I have so far, which works :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server srv = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(con));

var database = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database(srv, dbName);

database.Create(false);

database.Roles["db_datareader"].AddMember(???);
database.Roles["db_datawriter"].AddMember(???);
database.Roles["db_backupoperator"].AddMember(???);

srv.Refresh();
```

Noce the `???` ? I have tried

```
System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + System.Environment.UserName
```

and

```
System.Environment.UserName
```

but it fails (**update**) with the error `Add member failed for DatabaseRole 'db_datareader'.` with both values.

The problem is that when I create the database, I cannot coonect to it for some reason (using Dapper), from the same program. (**update**) I get the error message : `Cannot open database \"<database_name>\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user '<domain>\\<username>'` (where `<database_name>` is the database name, `<domain>` my logon domain, and `<username>` my Windows logon).

Am I missing something? Am I doing th right thing? I've tried searching the web, but it seems no one creates database this way. The methods are there, it should work, no?

** **Update** **

If I comment the `database.Roles["..."].AddMember(...)` lines, and I add a break point at `srv.Refresh()`, resuming the program from there solves everything.

Why a break point solves everything? I can't just break the program in production... nor break the program when creating the database everytime.

Comment: Are you saying that if you create a database with SMO then you can *never* connect to it with Dapper?  Can you connect to *any* databases with Dapper?

Comment: You say "it fails" when you try to add a member to a role, but what is the actual error message?  Have you printed out the strings that you are passing to see if they are what you think they are?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I can connect with Dapper when I create the database using MSSMS. My problem is when I procedurally create one with SMO.

Comment: Again, are you saying that if you create a DB with SMO, that you can ***never*** connect to it with Dapper?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, no, I'm updating the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the Dapper connection issue is a problem with SQL Server doing some of the SMO operations asynchronously.  In all likelihood, the new Database is not ready for other users/connections immediately, but requires some small time for SQL Server to prepare it.  In "human-time" (in SSMS, or a Breakpoint) this isn't noticeable, but "program-time" it too fast, so you probably need to give it a pause.

This *may* also be the problem with the Role's `AddMember`, but there a a number of things that could be wrong here, and we do not have enough information to tell. (specifically, does `AddMember` work later on? and are the strings being passed correct or not?)

Comment: I have tried putting the current thread to sleep 1 second (a *long* time in computer's term), but it made no difference. Does a breakpoint accomplish anything special that I can do programmatically and solve the issue?

Comment: @YanickRochon Did you comment out the `AddMember` calls too?  Also, try adding an `Application.DoEvents`

Comment: I did comment the `AddMember`. The `Application.DoEvents()` did not work either. I managed, somehow, to make it work by calling `database.SetOnline();` and `database.BrokerEnabled = true;` **then** sleeping 3 seconds on the current thread. It's weird, but it works. Although I wonder if it's really the way to go. (BTW: I does not work any other way.)

Comment: @YanickRochon Well `.SetOnline` makes sense, though I wouldn't think that `.BrokerEnabled` should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you've created the **user**, but no **login** for that user. Though I don't know the exact syntax, you're going to have to create a [`Login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.login.aspx). You'll want to set its `LoginType` to `LoginType.WindowsUser`. Further, you'll likely need to set the `WindowsLoginAccessType` to `WindowsLoginAccessType.Grant` and you'll need to set the `Credential` by building one, probably a `NetworkCredential` with the user name you want.

To put a visual on this, the `Login` is under the `Security` node for the `Server` in Management Studio whereas the `User` is under the `Security` node for the `Database`. Both need to exist for access to the SQL Server.

Comment: I've read that in other places too, but how do you implement this in C#? Can you provide an example? Furthermore, I *have* tried to execute a `CREATE LOGIN` and `CREATE USER`, but I got weird errors saying that the provided user existed under a different login... or some other weird thing like that.